# Instantiate Service with constructor http: Http in Angular 2

Tags: angular, service, angular-services, angular-http, angular2-testing

I have this service class here:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import {ReflectiveInjector} from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

import { Nota } from './nota.model';
import { HttpUtilService } from '../services/http-util.service';

import moment = require('moment');

const TIPOS_DOC : any[] = [
  {id: 1, nome: "Sem Referência"},
  ...

@Injectable()
export class NotaService {

    constructor(private http: Http, private httpUtil: HttpUtilService) { }

// methods ...
}
```

And I want to instantiate this Service in my spec file so I can call the methods and do my tests. But when I instantiate the Service I don't know how to use http: Http correctly. Here is my test file:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By }              from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement }    from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

import { HttpUtilService } from '../../services/http-util.service';

import { NotaService } from '../nota.service';

describe ('Tests for the service Nota response', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
      let http_service  = new HttpUtilService();
      let http: Http;
      this.nota_service = new NotaService(http, http_service);
  });
  it ('testes ...')
  ...

});
```

I don't get any syntax errors but this test file does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I am doing the tests right know.

First of all in Angular 2 you should never try to instantiate a service in your front-end(view) tests. Always use mocks. They are really easy to create and use.

Here is an example of mock file

```
// import the model you want to test and their dependencies
import { Post } from "../app/post/post.model";
import { UserTestMock } from "./mocks/user.test";

// create a normal class that will be the mock of your model
export class PostTestMock {

  static getMock(id: number): Post {
    const post = new Post(
      id,
      "Title of my post",
      "The body of my post ... end of body.",
      UserTestMock.getMock(1)
    );

    return post;
  }
}
```

Than at your test file you just need to use (import it) your mock

```
  it("Should test something", async(() => {
    let post = PostTestMock.getMock(1);
    // just an example of some function that you want to call
    yourTest.send(post)
  }));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check your code inside `beforeEach`, you are basically defining `Http`, but not instatiating it at all. Your NotaService will receive `NULL` reference. See:

```
  let http: Http;
  this.nota_service = new NotaService(http, http_service);
```

Common approach is to provide some Fake Http service (Mock) and inject it to your Service. You need to tell Angular 2: "if someone wants Http, give him Mocked version".

Use something like this in your test:

```
import { addProviders, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Http, BaseRequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { MockBackend } from '@angular/http/testing';
import { NotaService} from '../nota.service';

...

beforeEach(() => {
  addProviders([
    MockBackend,
    BaseRequestOptions,
    {
      provide: Http,
      useFactory: (backendInstance: MockBackend, defaultOptions: BaseRequestOptions) => {
        return new Http(backendInstance, defaultOptions);
      },
      deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
    },
    NotaService
  ]);
});
```

**Check this article for detail explanation**: [Testing Angular 2 HTTP Services with Jasmine](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/testing-angular-2-http-services-with-jasmine)
 and look for section *Introducing the HTTP Service*

Comment: I think addProviders is no longer used since Angular RC5.